# Perforce plugin for Eclipse is showing deleted files

Tags: eclipse, perforce

I am using the Perforce plugin for Eclipse, and for some reason it is showing deleted files in the depot. These are files that were deleted from the depot at some point, but Perforce is showing them along with "<- deleted ->" next to their filename.

When I use the regular P4V application to look at the depot, I do not see these deleted files.

The Perforce plugin didn't show deleted files before, so I'm not sure what happened.  I did upgrade my Eclipse from Indigo to Juno a few days ago, so maybe that affected the plugin?

So is there any way to get my Perforce Eclipse plugin to not show deleted files? I tried to delete the P4 connection in Eclipse and re-created it, but it is still showing deleted files.

Comment: In which view do you see deleted files?
Do you see submitted deleted files or just files that are open for delete?

Comment: I see the deleted files in the Perforce view.  These are deletions that were already submitted.

Comment: If you mean the "P4 Connections" view then you are browsing the perforce depots (on the server). It is normal and correct that you see deleted files there. You should not see deleted files in the regular "Project Explorer" view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest P4Eclipse plugin is suffering from numerous issues, so I downgraded to a previous version:

ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/bin.java/p4eclipse42.zip

That version doesn't exhibit the following problems that the latest version exhibits:

- showing deleted files in the depot
- not displaying an "up to date" message when you get the latest version and there aren't any new files
- not displaying a message telling you that you will need to resolve a conflict when you get a newer file from the depot that you already have checked out
- not displaying files in your changelists in alphabetical order by the full path